# org mode, html export of LaTeX equations with tikz support

Tags: org-mode, html

In my org-mode file I have some LaTeX equations using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and [tikz-cd](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd?lang=en) packages:

```
#+TITLE: Mixing tikz and equations

* An example

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[yshift=.7ex,r,"f"]
 \arrow[yshift=-.7ex,r,swap,"g"] & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
```

I have added tikz and tikz-cd packages to `org-latex-packages-alist` with value:

```
(("" "tikz-cd" t) ("" "tikz" t))
```

and I have customized `org-latex-pdf-process` as follows:

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
        '("lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
          "biber %b"
          "lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
          "lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

With this configuration, I can export the document to pdf:
[image]

However this does not work when exporting html:

[image]

If I try to export only the equation fragment (with `C-c C-x C-l`) I get this error:

> org-compile-file: File "/tmp/orgtexayOYxL.dvi" wasn’t produced. 
>   Please adjust ‘dvipng’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.

Unfortunately, the `org-preview-latex-process-alist` variable does not seem easy to configure... and I need help here.

**In short:** what would be a clean configuration to be able to export my org mode document both in pdf and html?

---

**Update:**

I do not know if it helps...

Adapted from https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/blog/tikz.html

```
#+HEADER: :file contour.png :imagemagick yes :eval no-export
#+HEADER: :results raw :headers '("\\usepackage{tikz}")
#+HEADER: :fit yes :imoutoptions -geometry 400 :iminoptions -density 600
#+BEGIN_src latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (-2,0) arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=-180,end angle=0] (-1,0) -- (1,0) arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=180,end angle=0] (2,0) -- (3,0);
\filldraw (-1.5,0) circle[radius=1mm];
\filldraw (1.5,0) circle[radius=1mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_src
```

works for **figures**, but I would like to make it works for **equations**.

Comment: The following sentence in the tikzcd package documentation indicates that `dvipng` is not the right tool for `tikzcd`: "It is important to note thatdviviewers will not display diagrams correctly. It is necessary to convert thedvifile topdforpsformat—or, even better, use a tool that generatespdffiles directly, such aspdflatex." Maybe, you should rather convert to pdf.

Comment: @Tobias thank you for your interest. I missed this from the doc, but in practice, I have not observed problems for the basic tikz figures I use (also see my post update). Also I am still interested by an answer as I really wonder how to cleanly configure Emacs/OrgMode to manage both html & pdf exports of equations with tikz (even if png convertion may not work properly in all cases)